# Get list data from envelope.response Android using Ksoap2

Tags: java, android, web-services, list, ksoap2

Good morning, 
i've this webservice with this method:

SOAP 1.1

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /Service_KompunetApp.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: webservice.kompunet.it
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetListaMarcheAutoOnTokenString"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListaMarcheAutoOnTokenString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <tokenString>string</tokenString>
    </GetListaMarcheAutoOnTokenString>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListaMarcheAutoOnTokenStringResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetListaMarcheAutoOnTokenStringResult>
        <status>boolean</status>
        <Message>string</Message>
        <Data>
          <Make>
            <makeid>int</makeid>
            <make>string</make>
          </Make>
         <Make>
            <makeid>int</makeid>
            <make>string</make>
          </Make>
        </Data>
      </GetListaMarcheAutoOnTokenStringResult>
    </GetListaMarcheAutoOnTokenStringResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My android method is LoadMakeList that accept only a string (it's a token generated randomly from webservice and sent to android app).

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_LOAD_LIST_MAKE_BY_TOKEN);

    request.addProperty("tokenValue", token);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =
            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_LOAD_LIST_MAKE_BY_TOKEN, envelope);

        SoapObject receivedObject = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

        //here how to i manage data list?
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       // message of exception
    }
```

How can i manage the list that i receive from webservice? Please help me! Thankx for any help!

Cris

Comment: Do you want to pass this SoapObject as string to LoadMakeList method? or parse SoapObject to ArrayList?

Comment: Ehm i would want parse a SoapObject to ArrayList. Thanks...

Comment: I have answered as you defined SoapObject to ArrayList. Always Welcome

Answer (score 0):

As you commented that you want to parse this object and make arrayList, I am sending you demo code to create list.

```
public void LoadMakeList(SoapObject soapObject) {
        ArrayList<ModelTest> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < soapObject.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            ModelTest model = new ModelTest();
            model.setAddress(soapObject.getPropertyAsString("your_property_name"));
            model.setName(soapObject.getPropertyAsString("your_property_name_1"));
            list.add(model);
        }
    }
```

and a demo custom model class:

```
/**
 * Created by Ramesh Kumar on 10/2/2015.
 */
public class ModelTest {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

    String name, Address;

}
```

By this code you get the idea how to make arraylist of custom model from SoapObject.

Note: I did not run this code as I am working on magento and parsed that response, by reference of that code I created it. Thanks